# Pass input function as a variable

Tags: python, input

I would like to create python script to be run in the terminal. Instead of the user setting the filenames to variable in the script, saving, and then running, I thought I could use `raw_input` for the user to add files of their own choice. The program then reads in the file, splices the values, does calculations, and ends.

So, I write a function that can handle exceptions:

```
 def function():
     inputFile = raw_input('Type in file name: ')
     if inputFile.endswith((".txt")):
         return True
     else:
         raise ValueError("Extension must be .txt")
     return inputFile
```

I then call the function

```
 function()
```

which prompts the user to give me the file.

```
 filename = function()
```

results in `NameError: name 'inputFile' is not defined`.

Now, I would like to automatically use what I have entered for `inputFile` above. However, if I use this variable in my code, it doesn't recognize the value. I thought that now `inputFile` is a defined variable, right?

Comment: What does "it doesn't recognize the value" mean? What actually happens when you run this and type something in?

Comment: Well, actually, what happens is an `IndentationError`. And, if you fix that, probably an exception telling you that there's no such variable as `exception`. Please give us a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); if you give us code that can't even get to the point where the problem happens, nobody can debug it.

Comment: Also, why have you tagged this `types` and `exception-handling`? Just throwing in random unrelated tags isn't going to attract more people who can help, it's going to attract people who read your question, realize it has nothing to do with their area of expertise, downvote, and leave.

Comment: you want to run PY files(this is input from the user) from the Python script?

Comment: @abarnert I get various errors. For instance, if I try to pass `filename = inputFile` on the next line, I get a `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s)`. What's the proper way to take that input value and use it? Let's say it's not a file, but just an integer---maybe that would help me understand.

Comment: @abarnert I am very sorry. I thought maybe this question related to exception handling. I am sorry. I have changed it.

Comment: @VivekSable Yes. I want to use that filename and then parse it later. For instance, I am working with a FITS file. I then use `pyfits.open(filename)' to read the data. https://pythonhosted.org/pyfits/users_guide/users_tutorial.html

Comment: I don't believe that `filename = inputFile` raises a `TypeError`. Again, show us actual code that will run and actually produce the exceptions you're talking about. Giving us code that doesn't demonstrate that problem, but does have a whole slew of other problems, and then vaguely describing some other code without showing it to us, isn't helpful.

Comment: `temp` is not defined in your edited post

Comment: And now it doesn't raise any exceptions at all (except the `ValueError` if you give it a non-`.txt` name). So it _still_ doesn't demonstrate your problem.

Comment: it should be `if inputFile.endswith((".txt")):` instead?

Comment: this won't make a difference, but it should be `inputFile.endswith(".txt")`.  there's no need for the second set of parentheses.

Comment: so now it's all good? works?

Comment: why are you returning `True` when the input is a text file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a basic problem with your function. I assume you are looking for text files (files ending in `.txt`), yet once you find one you never return the filename from the function; you just return `True`.

You need to modify your function like this:

```
def check_input_file():
    input_file = raw_input('Please enter a filename: ')
    if input_file.endwith('.txt'):
        return input_file
    else:
        print('File name should end in .txt')
        return check_input_file()

filename = check_input_file()
```

Comment: Thank you much for the help! I promise to work harder on my English.

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to tell, given that you keep giving us code that either raises completely unrelated exceptions, or that works with no problems.

But I think I can guess what you're after anyway.

In your *real* code, you do something like this:

```
def function():
     inputFile = raw_input('Type in file name: ')
     if inputFile.endswith((".txt")):
         return inputFile
     else:
         raise ValueError("Extension must be .txt")
     return inputFile

filename = function()

print inputFile
```

And it's that last line, which you've never shown us in any of your many edits, that raises this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "if.py", line 11, in <module>
    print inputFile
NameError: name 'inputFile' is not defined
```

The problem is that `inputFile` is a local variable, inside `function`. Once `function` finishes running, it no longer exists.

You *could* work around this by making it a global variable, by adding `global inputFile` to the top of `function`.

But you don't need to. It's already returning the value with that `return inputFile` (or at least sometimes it is… don't change that to `return True`…), and you're already storing the returned value with that `filename = function()`.

So, what you actually want to do is change the last line from this:

```
print inputFile
```

… to this:

```
print filename
```

---

Local variables are covered in one of the weaker parts of the tutorial, [Defining Functions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions). (That section is a wonderful guide if you're a C programmer who's used to writing compilers and interpreters; not so much if you're a novice…) But the Wikipedia article on [local variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_variable) explains the general idea pretty nicely.

Comment: you're missing that OP returns `True` when the file ends in `.txt`.  `inputFile` is never returned.

Comment: but otherwise, yeah, i bet that's what OP is doing.  good inferences.  this question should be closed, i think.

Comment: @dbliss: He had it returning `inputFile` at one point. I think back when it was getting the `NameError` about `temp`, or possibly before that, when it had two `IndentationError`s.

Comment: @abernert haha, this question is an abomination.

Comment: @dbliss: Anyway, I already voted to close, but apparently nobody else agrees and wants to give him a chance to actually ask his real question, so I figured I'd cut to the chase and anticipate what his real question almost certainly will be.

Comment: @dbliss: Actually, 2 close votes now… I'm guessing you're the other person who agrees?

Comment: i flagged it -- does that count as a vote?  i'm not sure i have enough rep to vote.

Comment: @dbliss: I don't think it counts. How do you have under 1K? You spend too much time writing good comments that help other people answer or edit questions instead of doing it yourself. :)

Comment: @abernert i'm getting up to 1K, little by little.  and thanks, same to you.  i always enjoy your comments.

Comment: @abarnert Thank you for the help! I am sorry I have caused so much trouble. I am still a learner. I have asked the moderators to delete this question. I will not ask these questions again.